# Can't run query using "localhost\sqlexpress"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying dynamically build an SQL Statement that includes linked server. That works. When I use "localhost" to reference the current local machine SQL Server, that doesn't work.

For example:

```
Select * From [LOCALHOST\SQLEXPRESS].[My_Database].[dbo].[My_Table]
```

However, if I specify my machine name instead, it will work.

```
Select * From [My_Machine\SQLEXPRESS].[My_Database].[dbo].[My_Table]
```

Why can't I reference Localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only reference servers that are listed under Server Objects -> Linked Servers as well as the local server via what you get back from @@SERVERNAME. Four part naming does not trigger a NETBIOS / DNS lookup. If you are referencing the local machine anyway, why not just use three part naming?

Comment: I have a store procedure that dynamically build up a sql statement by combine server name, database name, schema and table name together.  Good thing the integration test failed due the server name parameter that we pass in is Localhost.  I will have to figure out another way to build the sql.